# Entity Framework DisplayName is not the Table Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently in the process of upgrading .NET RC1 to RTM. As part of the upgrade process, I have to upgrade Entity Framework from 7.0.0-rc1 to 1.0.0. The [process is described here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html) and is pretty straightforward. As part of that process, there was a change to the [table naming conventions](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#table-naming-convention-changes).

I adding the corresponding code to `OnModelCreating` in my context.

```
foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Model = {entity.Model}");
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Name = {entity.Name}");
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Model = {entity.DisplayName()}");
}
```

As you can see, I'm printing out some of the information because the mapping isn't happening correctly. In those outputs, the `DisplayName` is remaining the default. So, `Gender` (my model) does not map to `GenderLookup` (my table). If it changes anything, I am also using Data Annotations and the Fluent API for mapping my table names to my models (I never leave the default). I'm not sure how this plays into it. Like:

```
[Table("GenderLookup")]
public class Gender
{
   // ...
}
```

and

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("PreExistingUser");
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued my search for what might be going on, and discovered [this announcement from Rowan Miller](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/167) which stated the following:

> Impact on existing apps
>
> If you upgrade an app from RC1 to RC2, you have several options:
>
> - If you are generating the database from the model, you can scaffold a new migration to apply the naming changes (or drop and recreate the database if you are using EnsureCreated() rather than migrations).
> - Manually specify table names to match what was chosen in RC1. This can be done in OnModelCreating or with the [Table] attribute. [See the docs for more info.](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relational/tables.html)
> - Use the code from the following section to bulk configure table names to match what was chosen in RC1.

After reading that, I dove back into my code and discovered that there were a couple tables that did not have the `[Table]` attribute or were not covered in `OnModelCreating`. (As my team is required to use those to prevent falling back on the defaults in the first place, this may have been missed in a review.)

Once I rectified that situation, everything worked as expected. I wanted to share in case anybody else ran across the same issue.